# One Zone always opens if any of the other Zones opens in a 3 Zone System

Tags: hvac

I have a three Zone HVAC System.

- One Zone (Zone 1) Opens up even if the thermostat connected to that Zone is Off, if any of the other two Zones (Zone 2 or 3) needs to open.
  -If this Zone (Zone 1) needs to Open up, it works fine.
- The other two zones (2 and 3) do not Open up.
- Zone 1 is connected to Nest with 5 wires including the C.
- Zone 2 just has 4 wires.
- Zone 3 is connected wirelessly.
- Zone 2 and Zone 3 are Honeywell Thermostats.
- The HVAC is Honeywell (HZ322).

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What are the size of your zones? Is zone 1 the largest? What is your heat/cooling device?   A/C units and heat pumps are difficult to zone properly, perhaps it always opens zone one to ensure adequate airflow, which is critical.  Did this just start happening?  Have recent changes been made?

Comment: If it ain’t broke don’t fix it… ie if someone else set it up and it is working then leave it alone. What are you interfering with it for? Why do you think you need to change it?

Comment: One zone must be always open

Comment: VtC because question needs more information and OP seems to have abandoned it.